# Finding double vowels in Array Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
              const gotCitiesCSV =
                  "King's Landing,Braavos,Volantis,Old Valyria,Free Cities,Qarth,Meereen";                      




                    let returnOnly = gotCitiesCSV => Array.from(gotCitiesCSV).filter(letter => 
                    'aa','ee','ii','oo','uu'.includes(letter)).length;
                     let callElement = document.createElement("div");
                     callElement.textContent = JSON.stringify(returnOnly)
                     document.getElementById('kata23').appendChild(callElement)
                     return returnOnly;

                     }
```

When i try to run my `code` nothing is returning. So not sure if i am not calling the double vowels correctly. Trying to return the items that has double vowels and as well return as an array instead of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you were nearly there but your logic was a bit wrong. You need to use `split` to break cities from `comma` and check each individual one against the vowels you have.

Need to use `includes` on **each** string found in filter function so that it can checked if they vowels.

**Live Demo:**

```js
const gotCitiesCSV = "King's Landing,Braavos,Volantis,Old Valyria,Free Cities,Qarth,Meereen";
let splitStr = gotCitiesCSV.split(',') //split in commas

splitStr.filter(function(x) {
  if (x.includes('aa') || x.includes("ee") || x.includes('ii') || x.includes('oo') || x.includes('uu')) {
    let callElement = document.createElement("div");
    callElement.textContent = JSON.stringify(x)
    document.getElementById('kata23').appendChild(callElement)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="kata23"></div>
```

Comment: Great Explanation

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a few things going on in that example, but i took a stab at creating a working solution for ya with explanations about whats going on

```js
const gotCitiesCSV =
"King's Landing,Braavos,Volantis,Old Valyria,Free Cities,Qarth,Meereen";

// 1. Array.from() wont split the list of cities into an array
const gotCities = gotCitiesCSV.split(',');

// 2. `returnOnly` is a function, not a result. it looks like you want it to be the result;
const doubleVowels = ['aa','ee','ii','oo','uu'];
const doubleVowelCities =  gotCities.filter(
  // filter in the cities which
  cityName => doubleVowels.some(
    // contain some double vowel (i.e., atleast one)
    doubleVowel => cityName.includes(doubleVowel),
  ),
)
```

which returns

```
> console.log(doubleVowelCities);
[ 'Braavos', 'Free Cities', 'Meereen' ]
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this